# C++ - Displaying and Storing Japanese Characters

Tags: c++, string, winforms, unicode, visual-c++-2010-express

So, I'm attempting to use C++ and Windows Forms to create an application that will help me study Japanese (for now, Hiragana and possibly Katakana only). The aim is to be able to create a program that has the user select the character sets they want to use (A through O, KA through KO, etc.), and either view the cards freely or have the program test them over the characters. For debugging purposes, I currently have the View button set to output 5 values to 5 different text boxes - the Roman pronunciation, the corresponding character, its position in an array in which all of the characters are stored, and a Boolean value.

My problem lies in the fact that the characters all show up as "?", and I get multiple warnings when I compile. An example of this warning:

> 1>c:\users\cameron\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\japanesecards\japanesecards\Form1.h(218): warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u3093' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)

This shows up 46 times, 1 for each Japanese character in the array. The array's declaration line is,

```
std::string hiraList[5][11][2];
```

An example of inserting a Romanji-Hiragana pair is,

```
hiraCheck[0][0][0] = "A";
hiraCheck[0][0][1] = "あ";
```

Finally, the Hiragana is being inserted into a text box using the following code:

```
System::String^ displayText = gcnew String(hiraList[x][y][1].c_str());
textBox5 -> Text = displayText;
```

Basically, given all of this, my question is - How can I get my form to display Japanese characters properly in a text box?

Comment: Use System::String or std::wstring, string types that can easily store utf-16 encoded Unicode text.  Prefix string literals with L, like L"あ", so the compiler knows they are const wchar_t*.  And [read this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: In which encoding are you saving your code files?

Comment: @DDrmmr I'm unsure. Where in VS can I find this info?

Comment: @crayzeedude File -> Advanced Save options

Comment: @DDrmmr I'm not seeing that option.

Comment: Also, @HansPassant - I'm unclear of how exactly to assign values to a wstring_t (some romanji is more than one letter) or System::String array. Could you please guide me to a webpage or something on how to do so?

Comment: I leave finding web pages to Google, they are much better at it.  Very hard to guess why you'd have a problem entering romanji text, it uses a Latin alphabet.  Japanese people use an IME.  Sounds to me you've got a chicken-and-egg problem, learning to write Japanese requires knowing the language first :)

Comment: If I know what you're saying, that's just it - I'm taking a Japanese course at my high school, and I'm making this program to help me study.

Comment: And I say that because obviously, a char is 1 character, so I'd assume wchar_t* wouldn't work because of romanji entries such as "KA" and "TSU". That is, if I know exactly what a wchar_t is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! I've done a bit of tweaking and experimenting with wchar_t, and I've found out a solution.

First, I reduced the hiraList array to a two-dimensional array, and moved the Hiragana characters into their own, array, defined like so:

```
wchar_t hiraChar[5][11];
```

And added values like so:

```
hiraChar[0][0] = L'あ';
```

Then, I went down to the code for the 'View' button and made a few changes:

Deleted the method for declaring and filling the displayText variable

Updated the line of code which assigns textBox5 its text value to read from hiraChar[x][y]

A line of the new code has been pasted below:

```
textBox5 -> Text = hiraChar[x][y].ToString();
```

In essence, the program now creates three variables for Hiragana - One to monitor check boxes, one to store the romanji values, and one to store Hiragana characters. When at least one check box is selected, and the View button pressed, five things are outputted to text boxes - the character, its position in the array (x and y are separate boxes), its romanji equivalent, and a 'True' value which was used earlier in development for debugging purposes.